# Where can I order a CD of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I live off grid, have **only** a **slow** dial-up internet, **and** only have power when running generator, (at this time), which means power about 4 hours a day.
Can I get just **one** copy of 12.04 without downloading?

Comment: I don't know if the cost will be too high for you or the time too long, but you can download using a BitTorrent (see the [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)). Torrent will resume without loss after any disconnection, so it will cope with erratic power and accidental disconnections.

Answer (score 6):

Since [2011](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/04/05/canonical_kills_free_ubuntu_cd_program/), [ShipIt](http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit), the old Canonical service that allows you to get free Ubuntu CDs has closed. However, you can still [buy one](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) (Canonical *Free* softwares are definitively not [free as in *free* beer](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)).

However, it seems that some local communities [continues to provide the shipment service for free](http://ubuntu-uk.org/free-cds/). Use the [Ubuntu Local Communities website](http://loco.ubuntu.com/) to find a team near of your country.

Answer (score 1):

As Sebf pointed out, you can get a physical CD from [Canonical's store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).

There are also various "freelancers" [selling CDs on Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007XG0B44) and other sites, but make sure to read the reviews before purchasing since they are NOT Canonical authorized so their quality may be questionable (but what they are doing is perfectly legal since it is open-source software.)

Note that Canonical will [stop shipping physical CDs/DVDs for non-LTS releases](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/canonical-ditching-ubuntu-cdsdvds-for-non-lts), which means that after 12.10, the next physical CD you can get you hands on from Canonical will likely be 14.04.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you simply download it instead of picking up a disk it would be less time wasting but if you really want a disk well here is the link

http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976

and then when you wanna upgrade to raring just do it from the software updater and put alert me of all new os updates instead of just the stable ones

Comment: she explains that she *can't* download...